# Cannot get postgreSQL to connect to port 5432

Tags: postgresql

Whenever I attempt to run the command `psql` from the very start of my program, it gives me the following error:

```
error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

But this code is being worked on cooperatively and works for my coworker using the same commands. He recommended running `sudo service postgresql restart` which I did, only to get the following jumble of an error:

```
LOG:  could not bind IPv4 address "127.0.0.1": Permission denied
2021-12-08 11:34:14.492 EST [673] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2021-12-08 11:34:14.492 EST [673] WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
2021-12-08 11:34:14.492 EST [673] FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
2021-12-08 11:34:14.494 EST [673] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
```

Unfortunately, absolutely nothing is already running on post 5432. I checked this myself running `sudo service postgresql status` and I get the message back that I'm expecting-- the port is down. I get this message `12/main (port 5432): down`

EDIT: PostgreSQL version 13.4, and whenever I check to see what port 5432 is running, it says the port is down, which I could only assume means nothing's currently running on it. Windows OS
Running `ps ax | grep post` gets me  `1316 tty1     S      0:00 grep post`

I've been scouring the depths of StackOverflow for awhile now, trying essentially everything, uninstalling and reinstalling, restarting my computer, I'm considering making a sacrifice to the Druid Gods of Computer Science at this point. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: OS and version? Postgres version? How was Postgres installed? Is another program using port `5432`?  What does `ps ax | grep post` show? Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: Something in /var/log/syslog or /var/log/postgresql... ?

Comment: Nothing in syslog, but posgresql just has a list of all the failed attempts I've submitted when I run `psql`

Comment: If you are doing `sudo service postgresql status` and are seeing `Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"` in the error then the Postgres server is not running on Windows. You are only checking if Postgres servers are using port 5432, not if another program is. That is why we need the information on the OS you are running the server on.

Comment: I am running on Windows, as it says in the question

Comment: You may be but Postgres is not unless Windows has changed its path separator from '\' to '/' and grew the `sudo`, `ps` and `grep` commands and has a 'Unix domain socket'. Best guess is Postgres is running in some sort of container on Windows.